# Convert video to flv or swf using php ?

Tags: php, linux

Can i use php to convert video file to .flv or .swf file ... i want to let the user upload video with any format and then my server convert the video on me website to .flv or .swf

i know that i can use the **ffmpeg** tool on my server, but it must be installed on me webserver

```
exec("ffmpeg -i ...");
```

Is there any php framework to help me in doing that ? any better solution would be appreciated  ?

thanks

Comment: Converting .flv to .swf is quite the task which I don't think PHP is currently capable of, not without mods.

Comment: php no, an external program called by php yes.

Comment: Seems like a decent question. Downvoter, do you care to explain?

Comment: Yes i agree @George Cummins .. i wonder why people are so quick him give him a minus

Comment: They are so many online video conversion sites that has good api that can work with PHP .... that can be a good alternative ..

Comment: @Baba Thank you .. could you give me links to good video conversation sites that have api work with php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way to approach this is to have a process on your server (could be your web server, could be a separate application server) that looks for videos uploaded to a given folder, converts them, and perhaps copies the result to a new folder.

Video conversion can take a long time.  Processing a video in the context of a user's request with a PHP wrapper (i.e. having them wait for a page result until conversion is complete) is impractical.  YouTube certainly doesn't work that way.

You could accomplish this in a number of ways (having a wrapper around `ffmpeg` is probably a reasonable approach), but all of those ways involve having the ability to install a program on a server that either runs continuously (e.g. as a service/daemon) or awakens periodically to look for work (e.g. via cron).

Answer (score 1):

Video processing and conversion is out of scope for PHP, which is primarily designed for processing hypertext. PHP video processing classes [exist](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/3747-PHP-Manipulate-and-convert-videos-with-ffmpeg-program.html), but usually as a wrapper around ffmpeg and similar software.